# React Native add border Radius to active tab bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to implement a top border radius to the active tab bar navigator to be like below image.

[image]

My code below is implementing a border radius to the whole createBottomTabNavigator but not as I expected above

```
<Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
            showLabel:false,
            activeBackgroundColor: COLORS.reddish,
            inactiveBackgroundColor: COLORS.transparent,
            style:{
                position:'absolute',
                bottom:0,
                right:0,
                left:0,
                elevation:0,
                height:55,
                borderTopRightRadius: 20,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 20,

            },
            
        }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon:({focused })=> (
                    <View style={{
                            alignItems:'center',
                            justifyContent:'center',
                            }}>
                        <Image 
                            source={icons.home}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            style={{
                                width:30,
                                height:30,
                                tintColor:focused?COLORS.white: COLORS.reddish
                            }}
                        />
                        <Text style={{
                            color:focused?COLORS.white:COLORS.reddish,
                            
                        }}>HOME</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
        />
     //code for other Tab.Screen
```

</Tab.Navigator>

[image]

Kindly assist

Comment: I faintly remember having issues with using the specific border radius' instead of just borderRadius. I don't know if this is possible for you but you can usually get around it by wrapping the original view in a view that holds the borderRadius styling as well as overflow: 'hidden'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out after going through React Navigation documentation.

To styles an individual tab I've added **tabStyle** in **tabBarOptions** props as seen in below code.

```
<Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
            showLabel:false,
            activeBackgroundColor: COLORS.reddish,
            inactiveBackgroundColor: COLORS.transparent,
            tabStyle:{ //Add this 
                borderTopRightRadius:20,//add border top right radius
                borderTopLeftRadius:20,//add border top left radius
                paddingVertical:3
            },
            style:{
                position:'absolute',
                bottom:0,
                right:0,
                left:0,
                elevation:0,
                height:60,

            },
            
        }}
        
        
    >
```

The results are as per below just as I wanted
[image]

Thank you @Ankit Patel.

I have not tried your method but i'll definitely try it

Answer (score 2):

I Added border radius to each tab item like this :

```
 <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: 'red',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          borderRadius: 200,
        },
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarOptions={{
        tabStyle: {
          borderTopRightRadius: 8, 
          borderTopLeftRadius: 8, 
          backgroundColor: colors.white,
        },
      }}
```

Answer (score -2):

activeBackgroundColor: COLORS.reddish, First remove this and

```
 <View style={{
            alignItems:'center',
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            backgroungColor:focused?COLORS.reddish: COLORS.white
            justifyContent:'center',
         }}>
```

in Tab.screen View Change this